# how select column name of oracle is lowercase?

Tags: php, oracle

In oracle: Table MS_USER : MS_USER (ID,PASS);

Code PHP:
if: `select id from ms_user;`
result:

```
 array (size=1)
  'ID' => string 'vnit2' (length=5)
```

i want get result:

```
 array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'vnit2' (length=5)
```

how select column name of oracle is lowercase?

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle you can do it like this:

```
select ID as "id" from ms_user;
```

Comment: i using php and connect to oracle

Comment: Thanks. i had call sql: SELECT id as \"id\" FROM ms_user in php